# gmapping parameters

Tags: ros, navigation, gmapping, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody! I would like to create a map with gmapping with 10x10 cells dimension and that every cells are bigger than my robot. Is it possibile? which parameters of gmapping do I have to modify?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190020/gmapping-parameters/) by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Theoretically those:

```
~xmin (float, default: -100.0)
Initial map size
~ymin (float, default: -100.0)
Initial map size
~xmax (float, default: 100.0)
Initial map size
~ymax (float, default: 100.0)
Initial map size
~delta (float, default: 0.05)
Processing parameters (resolution of the map)
```

However, 10x10 is a VERY small map with a VERY rough solution. This sounds really odd. Especially with a resolution of let's say 0.5m (guessed robot size) you will get localization accuarcy at best in this magnitude which is not preferable.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-08-13**:
ok thanks! I will try:)

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-08-13**:
with those parametrs I have a very BIG map! Are you sure abot xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-13**:
You need to set them differently of course. These are just the defaults.

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-08-13**:
ok so I I want 10x10 cell I have to modify this way?:

xmax=10;
ymax=10;
xmin=-10
ymin=10;

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-13**:
That depends how large the cells are. The min/max values are in meters.

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-08-13**:
my robot is 1m big. I want to have my robot smaller than the cells

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-13**:
The cell size is called delta here.

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-08-14**:
is it delta in meters?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-14**:
yes                .

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-08-14**:
ok thanks! so if i want cells 1m big do I have to set delta =1?